# Unique ids in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I'm about to deploy my first production version of a web service that uses MongoDB.
This web service could be prone to attacks (hackers).
I have been using the built-in Object-ID as unique identifier for each value, and this is exposed publicly (or at least to authenticated users).

Could this be a problem considering that it's built up on data such as, object creation timestamp, machine and process IDs etc (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/object-id/)?
Could it be that I'm giving away too much information about when the object was created, how many machines that is used to etc?
What would your recommendations be?

Comment: Is the creation time of an object sensitive data for your application?

Comment: No, I can't think of any reason that it could be..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really. It can't be used to graph your network or your machines or find hidden objects or to even graph your traffic and load times (as I have found out myself from trying).

For example, unlike an auto incrementing ID you cannot easily judge what time stamp or PID or Machine ID was used to create the next ObjectID. This makes it very hard to crawl for the hidden objects especially if you don't publicly link to them somewhere.

The PID and Machine ID are not very good at identifying anything about your network really and the PID can change almost any time it likes, whether the process was restarted or whether you restarted the server; or if you are using a language like PHP, every time a new connection comes in.

The machine ID is another piece of useless information that doesn't really give any meaningful results for anyone but your computer. I don't believe it uses the network interfaces ID (some drivers did) any more so it cannot be used to identify the machine externally.

So in short, not really.